# Model an Autoencoder with Haskell Grenade

Tags: haskell, deep-learning

I would like to create a network for an Autoencoder with the Grenade Deep Learning Library written in Haskell. 
It should learn to represent 265 Bits of input with a layer of 200 bits.
Thus, I declare the type:

```
type Auto = 
  Network
    '[ FullyConnected 265 200, Relu, FullyConnected 200 265, Relu]
    '[ 'D1 265, 'D1 200, 'D1 265]
```

However, when I try to generate a random network for this type by

```
randomAuto :: MonadRandom m => m Auto
randomAuto = randomNetwork
```

I get a type error like this:

```
Could not deduce (Layer Relu ('D1 200) ('D1 265)) arising from a use of ‘randomNetwork’
```

This surely is because the only `Relu` instance of dimension 1 is declared as

```
KnownNat i => Layer Relu (D1 i) (D1 i)
```

requiring that input and output are of the same size.

But how do you create an auto encoder with this library?

Comment: At a guess: that `'[ 'D1 265, 'D1 200, 'D1 265]` should be `'[ 'D1 265, 'D1 200, 'D1 200, 'D1 265, 'D1 265]`. But it's a pretty wild guess.

Comment: Yes, this compiles! Very good wild guess, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like activation functions count as "layers" (that don't change the dimension) in this library. So duplicate the dimensions that correspond to the relu layers:

```
type Auto = 
  Network
    '[ FullyConnected 265 200, Relu, FullyConnected 200 265, Relu]
    '[ 'D1 265, 'D1 200, 'D1 200, 'D1 265, 'D1 265]
```